# Cleaner way to handle Navigation in Typescript in React Native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, coding-style

Anyone here who knows a cleaner way then ´{ navigation }:{navigation: NativeStackNavigationProp}` in Typescript in a React Native cli project? I already tried many different things from stackoverflow but they didn't work.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator, NativeStackNavigationProp} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {Button, Text} from "react-native";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export const App = () => {
    return (
        <MyStack/>
    );
};

const MyStack = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Home"
                    component={HomeScreen}
                    options={{ title: 'Welcome' }}
                />
                <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }:{navigation: NativeStackNavigationProp<any>}) => {
    return (
        <Button
            title="Go to Jane's profile"
            onPress={() =>
                navigation.navigate('Profile', { name: 'Jane' })
            }
        />
    );
};
const ProfileScreen = ({ navigation, route }:{navigation: NativeStackNavigationProp<any>, route: any}) => {
    return <Text>This is {route.params.name}'s profile!</Text>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Note : Please note that you need to use React.FC to type check your functional components.

If you refer to [React Navigation's guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript) you will see that the correct way of type checking your navigation is:

#### Type check your stack first

```
type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: { title: string };
  Profile: undefined;
};

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
```

#### Type check your screens

```
type Props = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Home'>;


const HomeScreen:React.FC<{navigation:Props['navigation']}> = ({ navigation }) => {
  // code
}
```

or

```
    type Props = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Home'>
    
    const HomeScreen = () => {
          // code
          const navigation = useNavigation<Props['navigation']>()

}
```

You can use either of the two ways, I always use the hook, since it feels more clean to me.